# merge rows in pentaho PDI kettle

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I was wondering if I could merge 2 or more rows in pentaho?

example: 
I have 2 rows of

```
case:'001',
owner:'Barack'
date:'2017-04-10'

case:'001',
owner:'Trump'
date:'2017-02-10'
```

Then I want to have a mongoDB output :

```
case:'001'
ownerHistory:[
{
owner:'Barack'
date:'2017-04-10'
},
{
owner:'Trump'
date:'2017-02-10'
}
]
```

Comment: Your sample input has case 002 for the second row, is that a mistake or is there another way you select the rows to merge?

Comment: Thanks Cyrus, it was my mistake. it was supposed to be case 001... Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The **MongoDB Output** step supports modifier updates that affect individual fields in a document and the $push operation to add items to a list/array. Using those, you don't need to merge any rows, you can just send them all to the MongoDB Output step.

With the Modifier update active each next row will be either inserted if the case doesn't exist yet or have the owner added to the array if it does.

Unfortunately, if you run this transformation a second time with the same incoming data, it will add more copies of the owners. I haven't found a way to fix that, so I hope you don't have that in your use case.

Perhaps if you split the data and insert/replace the using the first record for each case, then do the $push updates for the second and later records you can manage it.

[image: MongoDB configuration screenshot]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I, unfortunately, was unable to get this is working.

I wonder what should I put for the datatype also. The options are only String, Number, Date, Boolean, Integer, BigNUmber, Binary, Timestamp, Internet Address.

Perhaps, if you could share a .ktr file it would be much helpful. (when you have time obviously)

and yes, ofcourse I will have more than 1 cases

Comment: I rewrote the answer to use built-in capabilties of the MongoDB output, rather than building the document layout from scratch.